# NodeJS CRUD api trouble with delete method

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, crud, http-status-code-400

I have been trying to get the Delete portion of my nodejs CRUD api for the past 2 days and I cannot figure out what is wrong.  I am still learning--there must be something that I am not seeing that is not causing it to work properly.

On the server side, my delete route looks like this:

```js
app.delete('/delete-lion/:id',(req, res)=>{
    // console.log('ID', req.body.id);
    var lion = lions.findIndex(lion=>lion.id==req.body.id);
    if(!lions[lion]){
        res.send();
    }else{
        var deletedLion = lions[lion];
        lions.splice(lions,1);
        res.json(deletedLion);
        res.send();
    }
})
```

And on the client side, this is what I have in (app.js... 'checky' is the id of the checkboxes next to each item to be able select and delete.)

```js
 function deleteData(id){
     return fetch('http://localhost:9091/delete-lion',{
        method: "delete",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: "include",
        body: JSON.stringify(id)
     })
     .then(response => response.json(id))
     .then(response=>{
        if(document.getElementById('checky').checked){
            document.getElementById(response.id).remove()
            return response.id
        } 
        
     })
 }



window.onload = function(){
    getData();
    document.getElementById('add-new-lion').onclick = ()=>{
        displayAddForm()
    };
    document.getElementById('deletey-lion').onclick = ()=>{
        deleteData(0)
        // console.log(e)
    }
}
```

this is the errors I receive in console:

app.js:111 DELETE http://localhost:9091/delete-lion 400 (Bad Request)
deleteData @ app.js:111

document.getElementById.onclick @ app.js:138

app.js:120 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
at fetch.then.response (app.js:120)
```

fetch.then.response @ app.js:120

Promise.then (async)

deleteData @ app.js:121

document.getElementById.onclick @ app.js:138

Comment: It’s your client side fetch. When the response isn’t JSON like in this case, it’ll throw.  Try response.text() and maybe throwing that step in a try catch.

Answer (score 3):

Your server is listening for DELETE requests at `'/delete-lion/:id'`. In this path, the `id` parameter is required. Your server will respond to

```
fetch('http://localhost:9091/delete-lion/1337'),
```

or

```
fetch('http://localhost:9091/delete-lion/omygoditsalion'),
```

but not

```
fetch('http://localhost:9091/delete-lion').
```

To fix your problem, you either need to remove the `/:id` from your route, or have your requests send the `lion.id` as a route parameter (referenced by `req.params.id` in your callback) rather than than in the request body. You could also make the route parameter optional by changing it to `'/delete-lion/:id?'`, but that would be confusing--you probably wouldn't want to suggest that the id parameter should be in the URI when your subsequent code expects it in the body.

Comment: This is it! My issue was that my URL looked like this: http://localhost:3000/deleteUser/?id=1234. I just had to insert userID like this: http://localhost:3000/deleteUser/1234

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass a separate body parameter to the Fetch API Call,
instead just append the "id" parameter to the Fetch call as follows :

```
function deleteData(id){
 let url = 'http://localhost:9091/delete-lion/'+id;
 return fetch(url,{
    method: "delete",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
    },
    credentials: "include" //No need for body since ID is passed as param in the URL
  })
  ...
  ...
}
```

On the server side, you will have to replace

```
var lion = lions.findIndex(lion=>lion.id==req.params.id);//body with params
```

This should fix it. And this is also RESTful as opposed to passing the "id" in the body

Comment: `let url = 'http://localhost:9091/delete-lion/'+id;` -- You need a slash between `delete-lion` and the `id`.